# How to get conditional Include children entity and his related entity

Tags: linq, entity

The following code work for me:

```
var query0 = DB.Plan
    .Include("UserCreate")
    .Include("UserUpdate")
    .Include("PlanTemplate")
    .Select(p => new
            {
                plan = p,
                planItems = p.PlanItems.Where(pi => pi.IsCommited == true && pi.IsLocked ==    false)
            });
var query2 = query0.AsEnumerable().Where(m => m.planItems.Count() > 0).Select(m => m.plan);
```

But the planItems related to another entities that I wanted,the following code do not work for me:

```
var query0 = DB.WorkEffortPlan
.Include("UserCreate")
.Include("UserUpdate")
.Include("PlanTemplate")
.Select(p => new
{
    plan=p,
    planItems = DB.PlanItem
    .Include("UserResponsiblePerson")
    .Include("TemplateItem")
    .Include("ItemState")
    .Where(pi => pi.PlanID == p.PlanID && pi.IsCommited == true && pi.IsLocked == false)
});
var query2 = query0.AsEnumerable().Where(m => m.planItems.Count() > 0).Select(m => m.plan);
```

The vs compiler is run OK,but when exec this code,I get the NullReferenceException in query0.

Is there any linq solution to get filtering children entity and his related entity?